# Every time I restart my symbolic link disappears?

Tags: directory, 19.10, symbolic-link

I have two different HDD, one to keep the OS and one to store all my media files. I created a symbolic link of my movies folder residing in my media HDD onto my Ubuntu 19.10 desktop. But the problem is whenever I reboot or shutdown and then open the symbolic link appears to be not working, showing a cross sign. How can I make the symbolic link stay valid even after reboot or shutting down and opening again?

Comment: Where is the drive mounted?  how is it mounted?   It's possible you aren't mounting the drive until after the link is detected as not being valid  (is it mounted via fstab? or some other method?)

Answer (score 0):

Your symbolic links points to a media HDD, which is only connected (mounted) on demand.

By default in Ubuntu, partitions different from the system partition, the EFI partition and eventually the swap, are *not* mounted on startup. They appear in the left pane of Files (nautilus), and are mounted only when you click that button.

Thus, to have your symbolic link work, you first need to open Files and click the media HDD.

Of course, in your case, you may prefer that your media drive is automatically available as soon as the system has started. To achieve this **you need to change the mount options of that partition**.

You can do so using the utility **Disks**.

- Select the disk where your media partition resides in the left panel, and then click the relevant partition in the graphical layout of the drive in the right pane
- Click the cog icon and select "Edit mount options"
- Turn off "User Session Defaults" so you can edit the mount options
- Check "Mount at system startup"
- Provide a valid mount point, i.e., a folder in your system where the contents of the new partition is to appear. If you wish, you could directly specify your "Videos" folder here, i.e. /home/

  Click "OK" when done.

If you mount in a system folder, e.g. /mnt/media, then make sure you change the ownership of the mount point if you want to be able to read/write in the root of your media partition.